# Copying files and keep duplicates

Tags: batch-file, command, xcopy, robocopy

i have a list of pdf file links from different folders.Is there a way to copy these files using a batch file to another folder and keep duplicate files? example below.

from

```
C:\my folder\file1.pdf
C:\my folder\file2.pdf
C:\my folder\file3.pdf
C:\my 2nd folder\file3.pdf
C:\my 3rd folder\file2.pdf
```

to

```
C:\backup\file1.pdf
C:\backup\file2.pdf
C:\backup\file2(1).pdf
C:\backup\file3.pdf
C:\backup\file3(1).pdf
```

i need to combined these files in Acrobat and print it later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
for %%a in (
"C:\my folder\file1.pdf"
"C:\my folder\file2.pdf"
"C:\my folder\file3.pdf"
"C:\my 2nd folder\file3.pdf"
"C:\my 3rd folder\file2.pdf"
) do for %%b in ("%%~dpa\.") do copy "%%~a" "c:\backup\%%~nxb-%%~nxa"
pause
```

The above code will create copy commands like this, if that will work in your situation:

```
copy "C:\my folder\file1.pdf" "c:\backup\my folder-file1.pdf"
copy "C:\my folder\file2.pdf" "c:\backup\my folder-file2.pdf"
copy "C:\my folder\file3.pdf" "c:\backup\my folder-file3.pdf"
copy "C:\my 2nd folder\file3.pdf" "c:\backup\my 2nd folder-file3.pdf"
copy "C:\my 3rd folder\file2.pdf" "c:\backup\my 3rd folder-file2.pdf"
```